# How to delete a zip file after its creation? File keeps being in use

Tags: powershell, zip

We are currently working on a script, which is zipping a certain file, uploading it to a web server via API and then delete it locally again.

This is our current code:

```
$sourceFile = "D:\myfile.txt"
$destinationFile = "D:\myfile.zip"

function Add-Zip
{
     Param([string]$zipfilename) 

     if (-not (Test-Path($zipfilename)))
     {
          Set-Content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
          (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false    
     }

     $shellApplication = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
     $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)

     foreach ($file in $input) 
     { 
          $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
          Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
     }
}

dir $sourceFile | Add-Zip $destinationFile
Write-Host "zip created"

# code to upload the zip here

Remove-Item $destinationFile
Write-Host "zip removed"
```

It creates the zip perfectly, upload works too, but when try to delete the zip file using `Remove-Item`, we get

> Remove-Item : Cannot remove item D:\myfile.zip: The process cannot access the file 'D:\myfile.zip' because it is being used by another process.

How can we get rid of this lock? Is there anything we can `.Dispose()` to be able to delete the file afterwards?

Comment: The ShellApplication Object is likely holding onto the file, you might just need to add `Remove-Variable -Force -Name shellApplication` to the end of your `Add-Zip` function to clean this up.

Comment: `foreach ($file in $input)` - What is $input ?

Comment: I can't replicate this, `Shell.Application` doesn't appear to hold locks on the files. Try using Process Explorer to check it's not something else that has a handle on it (AV maybe?)

Comment: There's mention of 'uploading to a webserver via API' but no code for this, so that may also be an avenue for investigation.

Comment: the code is exactly as I use it, including the comment there ;-) there is currently no upload logic. it's just a place holder for later.
Remove-Variable -Force -Name $shellApplication ends in an error too, sadly. "Cannot find a variable with the name 'System.__ComObject'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found another way here: https://danvers72.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/creating-a-zip-file-from-a-single-file/

This is my working code:

```
$sourceFile = "D:\myfile.txt"
$destinationFile = "D:\myfile.zip"

<#
.Synopsis
   Creates a new archive from a file
.DESCRIPTION
   Creates a new archive with the contents from a file. This function relies on the
   .NET Framework 4.5. On windwows Server 2012 R2 Core you can install it with
   Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-45-Core
.EXAMPLE
   New-ArchiveFromFile -Source c:\test\test.txt -Destination c:\test.zip
#>
function New-ArchiveFromFile
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]
        $Source,
        # Param2 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false,
                   Position=1)]
        [string]
        $Destination
    )
    Begin
    {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem") | Out-Null
    }
    Process
    {
        try
        {
            Write-Verbose "Creating archive $Destination…."
            $zipEntry = "$Source" | Split-Path -Leaf
            $zipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($Destination, 'Update')
            $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
            [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zipfile,$Source,$zipEntry,$compressionLevel)
            Write-Verbose "Created archive $destination."
        }
        catch [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException]
        {
            Write-Host "ERROR: The source $source does not exist!" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        catch [System.IO.IOException]
        {
            Write-Host "ERROR: The file $Source is in use or $destination already exists!" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]
        {
            Write-Host "ERROR: You are not authorized to access the source or destination" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    End
    {
        $zipFile.Dispose()
    }
}

New-ArchiveFromFile -Source $sourceFile -Destination $destinationFile

# code to upload the zip here

Remove-Item $destinationFile
```